# Internal Error 500 in Google Classroom API

Tags: python, google-api, google-classroom

When trying to do multiple things at once on Google API in Python, I get an "Internal Error - 500" when for some of the functions. Sometimes, when I run the **same** code, the error crops up on different lines.

This is the code from a method I'm using:

```
batch1 = service.new_batch_http_request(callback=callback)
batch2 = service.new_batch_http_request(callback=callback)
batch3 = service.new_batch_http_request(callback=callback)

batch1.add(service.courses().create(body=arCourse))
batch1.add(service.courses().create(body=ciCourse))
batch1.add(service.courses().create(body=dtCourse))
batch1.add(service.courses().create(body=drCourse))
batch1.add(service.courses().create(body=enCourse))
batch1.execute(http=http)
time.sleep(1)
batch2.add(service.courses().create(body=geCourse))
batch2.add(service.courses().create(body=hiCourse))
batch2.add(service.courses().create(body=icCourse))
batch2.add(service.courses().create(body=laCourse))
batch2.add(service.courses().create(body=maCourse))
batch2.execute(http=http)
time.sleep(1)
batch3.add(service.courses().create(body=muCourse))
batch3.add(service.courses().create(body=peCourse))
batch3.add(service.courses().create(body=reCourse))
batch3.add(service.courses().create(body=scCourse))
batch3.execute(http=http)
```

I have split it into batches and included a 'sleep' in between batches to avoid going over the 5 query per user per second limit on Google API, but am still experiencing errors.

A similar problem I found online was to use 'exponential backoff's but I'm not sure how to implement them into this code.

I can post a larger sample of my code if required.

Comment: Assume every request is going to fail individually, and implement exponential backoff for requests that fail. Sometimes Google will just return a 500 due to some issue on their end, just retry your request.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this guide](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/performance) to enhance the performance of your code.

> This document covers techniques you can use to improve the performance
>   of your application. The documentation for the specific API you are
>   using should have a similar page with more detail on some of these
>   topics.

Also, try to check your code with this [Python Quickstart guide](https://developers.google.com/classroom/quickstart/python) if there are some missing links in your code.

> Complete the steps described in the rest of this page, and in about
>   five minutes you'll have a simple Python command-line application that
>   makes requests to the Classroom API.